# Write Counting Numbers to a text file

Tags: python, file

I am having some difficulty figuring out how to take the user input and write the number to a file.

For instance, if the user inputs the number `50`, the program should create a text file with the numbers `1,2,3,....50` save the output in the file.

This is what I have so far and it works and saves the users input to the file.

I can't figure out how to break it down so it saves to the file starting at `1` and counts to the number inputted by the user.

```
def main():
outfile = open('counting.txt', 'w')

print('This program will create a text file with counting numbers')
N = int(input('How many numbers would you like to store in this file: ')

outfile.write(str(N) + '\n')

outfile.close()
print('Data has been written to counting.txt')

main()
```

Comment: Are you familiar with loops? I bet a loop would help. Research loops.

Comment: Think about the "flow" of your program. What is happening assuming your program starts at the `print` line? What does it ask for and what does it write to file? Does it seem correct to you? Debugging starts with asking yourself questions about the program, learning that skill now will benefit you a lot more in the long term. Good luck.

Comment: Kevin pointed you into the right direction. Just take the first result from googling "python loop"

Comment: How do you cause a variable to take on the values from 1 to a specified upper limit?  This is a basic programming skill that you pick up from your course materials or any language tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

I am using a for loop.

```
def main():
    outfile = open('counting.txt', 'w')

    print('This program will create a text file with counting numbers')

    N = int(input('How many numbers would you like to store in this file: '))

    for number in range(N):  # the variable number will get every value from 0 to N-1 in each iteration
        outfile.write(str(number + 1) + '\n')

    outfile.close()
    print('Data has been written to counting.txt')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, I figured out I need a loop but cant seem to structure it right to output correctly. After trying to run your example code I get the following errors.  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Gwfox/Documents/pythontest/test1234567890.py", line 17, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Gwfox/Documents/pythontest/test1234567890.py", line 9, in main
    for number in range(N):  # the variable number will get every value from 0 to N-1 in each iteration
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: @JM just convert it to int like you did before N = int(input('How many numbers would you like to store in this file:\n'))

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it using a combination of `join` and `map`. The `map` function will convert every integer in range [1,N] to a string, and the `join` function will concatenate all number using comma `,` as separator:

```
def main():
    outfile = open('counting.txt', 'w')

    print('This program will create a text file with counting numbers')
    N = int(input('How many numbers would you like to store in this file: ')

    outfile.write(",".join(map(str,range(1,N+1))))

    outfile.close()
    print('Data has been written to counting.txt')

main()
```